# problem? what problem?

Tags: mate, ubuntu-mate, error-handling

Every time I boot up my desktop, (Ubuntu Mate 20.04) regardless of the system I have it in, I get a message that says "System Program Problem Detected"
ok cool, what problem? unlike other Ubuntu warnings I have seen in the past, this message box doesn't have an option for further details.
I've looked through dmesg, and haven't seen any errors. in /var/log I see a variety of logs I could look at, syslog has some listing for "fail", mostly regarding pulse audio, and some missing color object in gdk. Seems like non critical stuff to me. where should I look for more details? I want to note that everything seems to be working fine, but I get this message every time I boot into my desktop. booting into a shell doesn't show any errors.

[image]

Comment: Check /var/crash also.

Comment: This isn't an answer, but it might be worth filing a Ubuntu bug/feature request, as that dialog could definitely be improved

Comment: looking in /var/crash/  wondering wtf wnck-applet is, I see a crash log of the wnck applet. so i go on and read that. it starts out like a normal log, then becomes this huge gobblty gook, all letters, with the occasional + / signs. ... loks like base64 encoding. wtf?
https://imgur.com/a/MAe6A3U

Comment: Yes, that file in /var/crash/ can cause this dialog on every startup. Removing files from there can help: https://askubuntu.com/a/1306228/1157519

Comment: When I was using Ubuntu MATE 18.04 for short time, I had this too. I don't know what it is, but as far as I was able to tell, this doesn't disturb anything and the system works fully normally. It's only an inconvenience that you have to click through this on every GUI login.

Comment: As for bug reporting, Im not sure how even to begin, as I do not know what part of the OS is generating this message box. Maybe I can assume its part of Mate DE, but I dont have enough useful details to create a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the comment of the user @Levente, I deleted my crash logs, (moved them out of /var/crash anyway) and rebooted. No strange message has shown up yet. The issue appears to be resolved.