# Ubuntu 20.04 have experienced an internal error

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fA6zE.png)

I just now installed ubuntu 20.04 on my virtual box and I am getting this error message.

I can't understand the error message fully. Should I delete the package that is causing this error message?

I have already installed ubuntu 22.04 on my virtual box and I was using for one week before it crashed completely so I uninstalled and installed ubuntu 20.04 instead.

Any advice would be of great help.

Comment: You installed Ubuntu Core 22. that is the only version of Ubuntu to use a single digit version number. If this is not correct please edit the question and give the correct version info.

Comment: I have edited my question and the problem is with my ubuntu 20.04 version.

Comment: When does this kind of error show up? Does a reboot fix the problem? And what happens after this message shows up? If you close this window, does the OS keep working?

Comment: The error has stopped popping after multiple upgrades. As for your question the error showed up every time I rebooted.

Comment: O.k. so in this case, chances are that some files containing an earlier crash report, got "stuck" in `/var/crash/`. In such case, cleaning out `/var/crash/` can do away with the pesky "system error" dialogs on startup. See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1306228/1157519